# VR View (Web) grabbing invalid URL

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis, http-status-code-404, virtual-reality

I'm trying to use [VR View for the web](https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview-web) to display a 360 degree image. I created a basic sample locally and it works without issue but once I got the code into my project, I'm getting a 404 error saying the resource couldn't be found.

The `vrview.min.js` file is converting my image path, entered like `image: 'images/myImage.jpg'`, to something like:

```
http://localhost:80/Project/index.html?image=http://localhost/Project/images/myImage.jpg&is_stereo=false&
```

IIS is not finding the image and the whole thing is throwing a big fat 404 server error.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>View 360 Image</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.addEventListener('load', onVrViewLoad);

            function onVrViewLoad() {
                var vrView = new VRView.Player('#vrview', {
                    image: 'images/myImage.jpg',
                    width: 800,
                    height: 700,
                    is_stereo: false
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div id="vrview"></div> <!-- Placeholder where the VR player will display -->
        </form>

        <script src="includes/vrview.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be fantastic. Thanks!

Comment: it's a path issue. You need to make sure you have the right path in the image: attribute. You should also make sure you have that image file in that path in your project. Keep in mind "images/" vs "/images/" points to different locations. The / will take you starting from the root, without it you are starting wherever the url it currently located.

Comment: @Liquidchrome - If I strip off the `http://localhost:80/Project/index.html?image=` and the variables and just paste `http://localhost/Project/images/myImage.jpg` into a browser, it shows the image perfectly.

Comment: So in your code, image: 'images/mem_off_tab.jpg' does that exist as http://localhost/Project/images/mem_off_tab.jpg ? Also try passing it to that url that is created... http://localhost:80/Project/index.html?image=http://localhost/Project/images/mem_off_tab.jpg

Comment: woops... meant to generic that filename up for the question. But yes, that exists.

Comment: @Liquidchrome - the second link, though, doesn't work. I'm unable to pass the image's URL as a parameter to the index page.

Comment: If that url works (http://localhost/Project/images/myImage.jpg) but it doesn't work when passing to the html as a parameter, then there must be some issue with the script including it on the page.

Comment: @Liquidchrome - any guidance you can offer on what that issue is would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try using this sample image from google as your image path like this: image: 'image: '//storage.googleapis.com/vrview/examples/coral.jpg', this is working for me on my local machine

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to use google's service url if you want to pass the url to load.
You are hosting vrview.min.js on your local server and it's passing it to your localhost which doesn't have the service running.

```
<iframe src="//storage.googleapis.com/vrview/2.0/index.html?image=//storage.googleapis.com/vrview/examples/coral.jpg&is_stereo=true">
</iframe>
```

VS.

```
<iframe src="//localhost/Project/index.html?image=//storage.googleapis.com/vrview/examples/coral.jpg&is_stereo=true">
</iframe>
```

Here is the slightly modified version of your html that I used to test on my local machine. The sample google image is loading for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>View 360 Image</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.addEventListener('load', onVrViewLoad);

            function onVrViewLoad() {
                var vrView = new VRView.Player('#vrview', {
                    image: '//storage.googleapis.com/vrview/examples/coral.jpg',
                    width: 1440,
                    height: 680,
                    is_stereo: true
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div id="vrview"></div>
        </form>
        <script src="//storage.googleapis.com/vrview/2.0/build/vrview.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

VR View docs: https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview-web

Comment: This was helpful and led me to the solution. Switching to the Google hosted source caused it to work. I normally would have stopped there but since I had it working in the sample demo I built a few days ago and the answer was simpler than I was making it. I had only copied over the vrview.min.js file and it required everything downloaded from github, not just the vrview JS.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer. I was only including the `vrview.min.js` file that you import on the page you want to display the VR player. There was a whole directory of files that were included in the archive downloaded from github. I mistakenly assumed most of the files were for a sample demo.

All my initial code was correct, I just was missing files that `vrview.min.js` linked to. Once I dropped the extra files into the correct folder, the 360 degree photo appeared as intended.

Comment: Could you please post list of file names and their correct order.